# offline web application design recommendation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, offline, rabbitmq

I want to know which is the best architecture to adopt for this case :

1. I have many shops that connect to a web application developed using Ruby on Rails.
2. internet is not reachable all the time
3. The solution was to develop an offline system which requires installing a local copy of the distant database.

All this wad already developed.
Now what I want to do :

- Work always on the local copy of the database.
- Any change on the local database should be synchronized with distant database.
- All the local copies should have the same data in other local copies.

To resolve this problem I thought about using a JMS like software eventually Rabbit MQ.
This consists on pushing any sql request into a JMS queue that will be executed on the distant instance of the application which will insert into the distant DB and push the insert or SQL statement into another queue that will be read by all the local instances. This seems complicated and should slow down the application.

Is there a design or recommendation that I must apply to resolve this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/). It's a non-SQL database that does exactly what you are describing automatically. It's used especially in phone applications that often don't have internet or data connectivity. The idea is that you have a local copy of a CouchDB database and one or more remote CouchDB databases. The CouchDB server then takes care of teh replication of the distributed systems and you always work off your local database. This approach is nice because you don't have to build your own distributed replication engine. For more details I would take a look at the 'Distributed Updates and Replication' section of their [documentation](http://couchdb.apache.org/docs/overview.html).

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually the application is already developed with mysql during 2 years and I can't change to couchDB now

Comment: you think the PostgreSQL replication is better than mysql ? and that it is easy to convert the database into "PostgreSQL"?

Comment: I'm not a DBA, so I can't really answer that question. Both PostgreSQL and MySQL have replication, what you want is more complex though. You need a distributed replication engine with multiple write nodes. This is a lot harder to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that but essentially you are developing your own replication engine. Those things can be a bit tricky to get right (what happens if m1 and m3 are executed on replica r1, but m2 isn't?) I wouldn't want to develop something like that unless you are sure you have the resources to make it work.

I would look into existing off-the shelf replication solution. If you are already using a SQL DB it probably has some support for it. Look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) for more details if you are using MySQL

Alternatively, if you are willing to explore other backends, I heard that CouchDB has great support for replication. I also heard of people using git libraries to do that sort of thing.

**Update**: After your comment, I realize you already use MySql replication and are looking for solution for re-syncing the databases after being offline.

Even in that case RabbitMQ doesn't help you at all since it requires constant connection to work, so you are back to square one. Easiest solution would be to just write all the changes  (SQL commands) into a text file at a remote location, then when you get connection back copy that file (scp, ftp, emaill or whatever) to master server, run all the commands there and then just resync all the replicas.

Depending on your specific project you may also need to make sure there are no conflicts when running commands from different remote location but there is no general technical solution to this. Again, depending on the project, you may want to cancel one of the transactions, notify the users that it happened and so on.

Comment: BTW RabbitMQ requires constant connection to work. You can work around this by creating a local buffer of messages and then pushing them all to server once you have connection.

Comment: Agreed. Also, there has to be a conflict resolution code. What happens if client 1 and client 2 have modified record 1 offline and then synced? Whose change "wins"? If manual resolution is required, how's that handled?

Comment: thx for you help,
I'm using mysql replication, but when I go into offline mode, i'm obliged to stop replication, since the slave (witch is the mysql local copy). Now this replication is very slow specially with a big database. don't know rabbitmq is the good solution or no ?

Comment: You welcome, I guess I am not entirely clear on what exactly is the issue you are facing. I don't see how RabbitMQ can help since it won't work offline either. I've added a general solution to my answer above, if it is not what you are looking for, can you please clarify? Especially you mention that the process is slow - what exactly is slow? We use mysql replication all the time and it works reasonably fast for a lot of data.

Comment: Just to clarify - how often this resync needs to happen? Once a day? Or every minute?

Comment: the database is big (4Go) and sometimes it doesn't replication.
rabbitmq we will only use the online mode . I want to do : work always on the local copy of the database and any change on the local database should be synchronized with distant database. after the system supports the distribution of the message to different subscribers